# TrustKit with SHA256withRSA

Tags: ios, swift, pinning

I'm trying to configure SSL pinning in my app with TrustKit but I'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'TrustKit configuration invalid', reason: 'TrustKit was initialized with an invalid value for TSKPublicKeyAlgorithms for domain xxx.com'

The server is using `SHA256withRSA` as a signature algorithm. On the [documentation](https://datatheorem.github.io/TrustKit/documentation/Public%20Key%20Algorithm%20Keys.html#/c:@kTSKAlgorithmRsa4096) page of the TrustKit there's only `kTSKAlgorithmRsa2048` and `kTSKAlgorithmRsa4096` (I tried both of them).

Is it possible to use TrustKit and SHA256withRSA?

Comment: I think kTSKAlgorithmRsa2048 is the correct one for SHA256 hash key. The issue is not in the algorithm I suppose.